# JQuery autocomplete no muestra ñ sino la entidad HTML &#209;

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Tengo un problema con la presentacion del contenido de las coincidencias que se muestran en un textbox con la libreria autocomplete de JQuery ya que mi texto lleva `ñ` y pone simbolos raros, creo que no esta decodificando bien mi texto pero no se cómo corregir este problema.

Hago una llamada AJAX a una página que me devuelve los resultados de coincidencia y siento que el problema esta en el AJAX:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnBusca").css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $("#filtroBusqueda").change(function () {
            var op = $(this).val();

            switch (op) {

                case "rs":
                    $("#rs").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    $("#ln").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#nc").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#btnBusca").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    break;
                case "ln":
                    $("#ln").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    $("#rs").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#nc").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#btnBusca").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    break;
                case "nc":
                    $("#nc").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    $("#rs").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#ln").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#btnBusca").css({ 'display': 'block' });
            }
        });

        $("#txtRazon").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "coincidenciaRazonSocial",                    
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        q: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.nombre,
                                value: item.nombre,
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<div>
    <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Búsqueda</h5>
    <form id="formularoBuscar" method="post" class="form-horizontal " action="#">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Filtro</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-11">
                        <select name="filtroBusqueda" id="filtroBusqueda" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Opción</option>
                            <option value="rs"> x Razón social</option>
                            <option value="ln">x Línea</option>
                            <option value="nc">x Número cuenta</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rs" style="display: none">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Razón social</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRazon" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="ln" style="display: none">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Número telefonico</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTelefono" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="nc" style="display: none">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Número cuenta</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCuenta" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group" id="btnBusca">
                    <label class="col-lg-1 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-11">
                        <button type="button" id="btnBuscarAdenda">Buscar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

mi json que devuelve
[image: Mismo texto en el JSON con Ñ]

Comment: Verificar si la codificación de su documento es utf8 `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: verificaste que desde donde obtienes esos datos llega con ñ?

Comment: @sioesi si lleva ñ y tambien he colocado el meta utf-8

Comment: @Ivxn con el editor de texto que estas trabajando, guarda el archivo con encoding utf8

Comment: Esto **no es** un problema de codificación en UTF, sino que están codificadas las entidades HTML

Comment: @Mariano y se puede hacer algo para resolver el problema?

Comment: Estoy escribiendo la respuesta, pero quería evitar que se siga por ese lado... De todas formas, sería bueno que verifiques en tu archivo en `./coincidenciaRazonSocial` que sólo hay entidades con números, como `&209;`, y que no hay entidades con nombres como `&amp;` o `&aacute;`, etc.

Comment: Habias dicho "si lleva ñ" cuando ahora muestras tu json y viene mal desde donde lo envias. debes decodificar tu dato desde donde lo estas viendo

Comment: @Ivxn, si lees la doc de `jQuery Autocomplete`, dice: *Independent of the variant you use, the label is always treated as text. If you want the label to be treated as html you can use [Scott González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js).* PERO! si la usas empezaras a correr riesgo de [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @Marcos Gallardo no, es VB.NET

Comment: @sioesi si es lo que vi que esta devolviendo desde mi pagina las letras raras, lo que pasa que revise mi BD unicamente y los registros si llevan ñ

Comment: No conozco de VB, pero puedes probar con `Dim nombre =Encoding.Convert(utf8, @item("razon_social"), utf8Bytes)`

Comment: Puedes probar usando [`HttpUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se muestra en la imagen, no es un problema de codificación en UTF, sino que se están recibiendo del archivo de autocompletado (`./coincidenciaRazonSocial`) entidades HTML. En el caso de la `Ñ`, codificado como `&#209;`.

Para solucionarlo, podemos modificar la respuesta recibida por AJAX en esta parte del código:

```js
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
            label: item.nombre,
            value: item.nombre,
        }
    }));
}
```

Llamando a una función para decodificar:

```js
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
        var nombreDecodificado = decodificarEntidadesHTMLNumericas(item.nombre);
        return {
            label: nombreDecodificado,
            value: nombreDecodificado
        }
    }));
}
```

Y utilizar la siguiente función para convertir cualquier entidad decimal en su caracter correspondiente:

```js
function decodificarEntidadesHTMLNumericas(texto) {
    return texto.replace(/&#(\d{1,8});/g,function (m, ascii) {
        return String.fromCharCode(ascii);
    });
}
```

Nota: esta función sólo aplica para entidades numéricas decimales como la mostrada en la imagen (`&#209;`), y no reemplaza otras como `&aacute;`, `&gt;` o `&#x03A3;` (hexadecimal).

---

Para mostrar un ejemplo, subí un [archivo de texto](http://mariano.freevar.com/34461/coincidenciaRazonSocial.txt) con 3 items (`"DISE&#209;O 01"`, `..02` y `..03`), que obtendremos por AJAX:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtRazon").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://mariano.freevar.com/34461/coincidenciaRazonSocial.txt",                    
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        var nombreDecodificado = decodificarEntidadesHTMLNumericas(item.nombre);
                        return {
                            label: nombreDecodificado,
                            value: nombreDecodificado
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });

});

function decodificarEntidadesHTMLNumericas(texto) {
    return texto.replace(/&#(\d{1,8});/g,function (m, ascii) {
        return String.fromCharCode(ascii);
    });
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Búsqueda</h5>
    <form id="formularoBuscar" method="post" class="form-horizontal " action="#">
        <div id="rs" style="display: block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Razón social</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRazon" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: la funcion me marca error en " =>"

Comment: @lvxn Agregué un snippet y modifiqué la función con una versión no tan moderna

Comment: si era algo que no sabia como hacerlo gracias bro

Comment: amigo ahora tengo un problema con un ampersond me aparece este codigo "&amp;" como lo puedo integrar en la funcion con la que me ayudaste

Comment: Estaba por contestarte cuando vi que publicaste una nueva pregunta y respondí ahí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35802/127

Answer (score 2):

Ya que los registros llegan codificados como [entidades HTML](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) en el json, se me ocurren 2 posibles soluciones

1. Parchar el `jQuery Autocomplete` para que use el valor de `label` como `HTML` (innerHTML) en lugar de `texto` (innerText).

   En la [doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), existe el link a la [extension de Scott González](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js) que hace esto.
2. Decodificarlos antes de devolverlos.

   En `coincidenciaRazonSocial`, deberias:

   - **El nombre NO esta codificado en la DB**: Controlar que no estes codificando el `nombre`. Por ejemplo:

     ```
     //PHP
     $empresa['nombre'] = htmlentities($empresa['nombre']); // No hacer esto

     // ASP.NET
     Dim nombre As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(nombreEmpresa) // No hacer esto
     ```
   - **El nombre SI esta codificado en la DB**: Entonces deberias decodificarlos. Por ejemplo:

     ```
     // PHP
     $empresa['nombre'] = html_entity_decode($empresa['nombre']); // decode el nombre

     // ASP.NET
     Dim nombre As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(nombreEmpresa)
     ```

Comment: gracias tambien funciona

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso estuve trabajando con CodeIgniter y Jquery, lo que me funcionó fue usar el siguiente método

```
public function autocompletar($q){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('nombre', $q);
$query = $this->db->get('empresa');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $new_row['label']=htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['nombre']));
    $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
    $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
  }
  echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
}
}
```

En el label uso **htmlspecialchars** y con eso solucioné el tema.

Saludos