# Decodificar entidades HTML &#209 y &amp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui

Estoy usando la librería autocomplete de JQuery. Actualmente tengo una función que decodifica entidades HTML de tipo numérica -> `&#209;`, pero lo que no sé es cómo integrar a la función entidades de este tipo -> `&amp;`.

Mi función:

```js
function decodificarEntidadesHTMLNumericas(texto) {
    return texto.replace(/&#(\d{1,8});/g, function(m, ascii) {
        return String.fromCharCode(ascii);
    });
}
```

No sé cómo integrar la expresión regular para que decodifique ambos casos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se puede realizar de 2 formas:

1. Utilizando el [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), y creando un textarea que usamos para que el navegador se encargue de todo. Tiene como ventaja que permite decodificar todos los casos:

   ```js
   function decodificarEntidadesHTML(html) {
       var texto = document.createElement("textarea");
       texto.innerHTML = html;
       return texto.value;
   }
   ```

   O, el mismo código, pero evitando crear el textarea una y otra vez:

   ```js
   decodificarEntidadesHTML = (function(html) {
       var texto;
       return function(html){
           texto = texto || document.createElement("textarea");
           texto.innerHTML = html;
           return texto.value;
       }
   })();
   ```

2. Editar la función sólo para reemplazar los casos que te interese. Tiene como ventaja que se realiza directo con una función, no necesita ser ejecutado en un navegador, y se evita estar creando elementos en el DOM. Como desventaja, que no cubre todos los casos, o que sería tedioso incorporar la [lista completa de entidades](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) en la función:

   ```js
   function decodificarEntidadesHTML(texto) {
       return texto.replace(/&(?:#(?:(\d{1,8})|x([a-z0-9]{1,8}))|(\w+));/gi, function(m, ascii, hex, entidad) {
           if (entidad) {
               switch (entidad) {
                   case "amp":
                       return "&";
                   case "aacute":
                       return "á";
                   //agregar otros...
                   default:
                       return "&" + entidad + ";";
               }
           } else {
               var dec = parseInt(ascii,10) || parseInt(hex,16);
               return String.fromCharCode(dec);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: perfecto gracias amigo

Answer (score 4):

Usando `jQuery`:

```
function decodificarEntidadesHTML (texto) {
  return $('<textarea \>').html(texto).text();
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```js
function decodificarEntidadesHTML (texto) {
  return $('<textarea \>').html(texto).text();
}

// 
$('#entrada').val('Bonnie<b>&amp;</b>Cliet');

$('#traducir').on('click', function(){
  var resultado = decodificarEntidadesHTML($('#entrada').val());
  $('#resultado').text(resultado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Traducir: <textarea id="entrada"></textarea><br/>
<button type="button" id="traducir">Traducir</button><br/>
Traducción: <div id="resultado" style="display: inline"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Respuesta tomada de https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700369/1845602

```js
 function decode(str) {
   var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
   elem.innerHTML = str;
   return elem.value;
 }
 console.log(decode("&amp;&#209;"))
```

Recomiendan usar un textarea en lugar de un div para mitigar vulnerabilidades de XSS.